# Constructing a Tree from an arithmetic expression

Tags: java, tree, stack, adt

I'm pretty lost at the moment on how I would go about implementing this Tree, I'm trying to construct a Tree from a string representation of input "(4 + 6) + (2 + 3)". How would I go about making a Tree from two Stacks?

```
  public class Tree {

        private Stack opStk = new Stack();
        private Stack valStk = new Stack();
        private Tree parent = null;


        public Tree(String str){

            System.out.println((EvaluateExpression(str)));

        }   

        public void doOperation() { 

        Object x = valStk.pop();
        Object y = valStk.pop();
        Object op = opStk.pop();

        if ((Integer) x <= 0 || (Integer) y <= 0){ 
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        }
        if (op.equals("+")) {
            int sum = (Integer) x + (Integer) y;
            valStk.push(sum);
        }

        }

        public void repeatOps(char refOp) { 

            while (valStk.count() > 1 && 
                prec(refOp) <= prec((char)opStk.pop())) { 
                doOperation();  
            }   

        }

        int prec(char op) {
            switch (op) {

                case '+':
                case '-':
                    return 0;
                case '*':
                case '/':
                    return 1;
                case '^':
                    return 2;

                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + op);
            }
        }

        public Object EvaluateExpression(String str) { 

            System.out.println("Evaluating " + str);
            Scanner s = null;

            try {
                s = new Scanner(str);

                //while there is tokens to be read
               while (s.hasNext()) {

                   //if token is an int
                  if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                      //read it 
                    int val = s.nextInt();
                    if(val <= 0) { 
                        throw new NumberFormatException("Non-positive");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Val " + val);
                    //push it to the stack
                    valStk.push(val);
                  } else { 
                      //push operator
                      String next = s.next();
                      char chr = next.charAt(0);
                      System.out.println("Repeat Ops " + chr);
                      repeatOps(chr);
                      System.out.println("Op " + next);
                      opStk.push(chr);
                  }
                  repeatOps('+');
                }  

            } finally {
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Should be the result: " + valStk.pop());
           return valStk.pop();

        }
```

Comment: Maybe just convert the statement to polish notation? Or even recursively handle parenthetical expressions.

Comment: I've tried to follow ShuntingYard algorithm but I think somewhere along the line I have severely made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions to make that might set you on the right path (hopefully).

Firstly I suggest your expression tree follow the [Composite Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). It works very well for these types of hierarchies. For your purpose it would look something like:

```
interface Expression {
    int getValue();
}

class Constant implements Expression {
    private int value;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Operation implements Expression {
    private Expression operand1;
    private Operator operator;
    private Expression operand2;
    public int getValue() {
        return operator.apply(operand1, operand2);
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need any concept of operator precedence or parentheses: it's entirely implicit in how the tree is constructed. For example "3 + 4 * 2" should result in a tree "(+ 3 (* 4 2))" while "(3 + 4) * 2" should result in a tree "(* (+ 3 4) 2)".

Secondly I suggest you make your operators into an enum rather than relying on the string values:

```
enum Operator {
    TIMES((n1, n2) -> n1 * n2),
    DIVIDE((n1, n2) -> n1 / n2),
    PLUS((n1, n2) -> n1 + n2),
    MINUS((n1, n2) -> n1 - n2);

    private final BinaryOperator<Integer> operation;
    Operator(BinaryOperator<Integer> operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
    public int apply(int operand1, int operand2) {
        return operation.apply(operand1, operand2);
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it's trivial to add new operators without changing the structure of the tree at all.

Thirdly I suggest you split your conversion from string to expression tree into two steps. The first is to convert from string to tokens and the second from token to trees. These are call lexical and semantic analysis in the jargon.

If you are using the shunting yard algorithm for the semantic analysis then keep in mind that the output stack will hold `Expression` instances ready to become operands. I can give you more detail on how to shunt operators but it's probably worth you giving the suggestions above a try first.